# [rospack] Error: package 'rviz' not found

Tags: ros, rviz, environment, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been using ROS for a couple of years and Rviz has been working satisfactorily till now. I'm not sure what I've done but I'm getting the error mentioned in the question ( [rospack] Error: package 'rviz' not found ) while executing the following statements:

```
rosrun rviz rviz 
rospack find rviz
```

Yes, I have sourced the required directories, this is the output to echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

```
/home/rohit/glocal/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

ps. My original error was that one of my launch files which runs the rviz node was giving the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: rviz
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/rohit/glocal/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

This made me suspect that my rviz package wasn't being found which is the primary error according to me. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258155/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27rviz%27-not-found/) by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-29**:
Your observation is right IMO. Next question might be; is there RViz on your computer?

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2017-03-29**:
I would think that it should be there cause I've been using it till yesterday. Any way that I can check if it's there?

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2017-03-30**:
Thanks mate, you were right. Somehow my RViz got deleted. So I just installed it again from apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd run these commands.

```
apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-rviz
rospack find rviz
cd %YOUR_CATKIN_WS%/src && find . -iname rviz
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nullspace](https://answers.ros.org/users/57539/nullspace/) on 2020-09-02**:
this did not solve my issue
apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-rviz:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 1.14.1-1focal.20200826.191801
Version table:
1.14.1-1focal.20200826.191801 500
500 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
rospack find rviz:
[rospack] Error: package 'rviz' not found

$ cd %YOUR_CATKIN_WS%/src && find . -iname rviz
-bash: cd: %YOUR_CATKIN_WS%/src: No such file or directory

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-09-04**:
@nullspace  Please consider opening a new question (and link to it from here). Comment section is not meant to open a new question :)